# List<> with numbers and text

Tags: c#, .net, list

Is there a `List<>` similar to a two dimension array?  For each entry there is a number and text.

Comment: Why not just create a class that holds the number and the text that goes together?

Comment: Google > c# collections > 1st link wow, the answer...

Comment: and you require 31 minutes to mention this? :D @t3chb0t

Comment: @dotctor: yes it happens, perhaps because I'm not paid for giving immediate answers and I also do other suff in the meantime :-]

Comment: @t3chb0t good job! Google is a friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many options, I describe some of them for you

1. use `Dictionary<int, string>`
   **Pros**:  very fast lookup
   **Cons**:  you can not have two string with same number, you don't have a `List`

   ```
   var list2d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
   list2d[1] = "hello";
   list2d[2] = "world!";
   foreach (var item in list2d)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
   }
   ```
2. use `Tuple<int, string>`
   **Pros**:  very simple and handy tool, you have a `List`
   **Cons**:  `Tuple`s are immutable, you can not change their values once you create them, reduces code readability (`Item1`, `Item2`)

   ```
   var list2d = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
   list2d.Add(new Tuple(1, "hello"));
   list2d.Add(Tuple.Create(1, "world");
   foreach (var item in list2d)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", item.Item1, item.Item2);
   }
   ```
3. use a defined class,
   **Pros**:  you have a `List`, very customizable
   **Cons**:  you should write more code to setup

   ```
   public class MyClass
   {
      public int Number { get; set; }
      public string Text { get; set; }
   }

   var list2d = new List<MyClass>();
   list2d.Add(new MyClass() { Number = 1, Text = "hello" });
   list2d.Add(new MyClass { Number = 2, Text = "world" });
   foreach (var item in list2d)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", item.Number, item.Text);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`Dictionary<int,String>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Sample:**

```
Dictionary<int,string> samp = new Dictionary<int,string>();
dictionary.Add(1, "text1");
dictionary.Add(2, "text2");
```

Or, have a custom class which defines your requirement

```
public class Sample
{
   public int Number;
   public string Text;
}
```

**Sample:**

```
List<Sample> req = new List<Sample>();
Sample samObj = new Sample();
samObj.Number = 1;
samObj.Text = "FirstText";
req.Add(samObj);
```

Comment: use automatic properties instead of public fields in classes

Answer (score 5):

Custom class or dictionary are good options, you can also use the Tuple generic...

```
var i = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
```

Dictionary requires that whatever value is used as key must be unique. So not ideal without uniqueness.

A custom class is preferable if you don't mind a little more code and gives you scope to extend later on if you decide you want other data in there.

Tuple is quick and easy but you lose readability and objects can not be edited.

Answer (score 4):

Define a class wih a string and an int property

```
public class MyClass 
{ 
  public string MyStr {get;set;} 
  public int MyInt {get;set;} 
}
```

then create a list of this class

```
List<Myclass> myList = new List<MyClass>();

myList.add(new MyClass{MyStr = "this is a string", MyInt=5});
```

Comment: consider PascalCaseNaming for `C#` classes

Answer (score 3):

Hope it will help

```
public class DATA
{
    public int number;
    public string text;
}

List<DATA> list = new List<DATA>();
```

Comment: `DATA` is not a suitable name for classes, consider PascalCaseNaming

Comment: @dotctor  The compiler doesn't care what case you use for your identifiers.  Perhaps what you mean is that common `convention` suggests using camel case.

Comment: suitable != valid. and no! I suggest using pascal case @PeterM

Comment: @dotctor The `suitability` of identifiers is a stylistic and non-functional choice, for which `convention` is a guideline and not an absolute.